# ABAP : Fill an I/O field of a Screen from Database

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have just started writing a program using ABAP, I have a screen (named 9007) that contains an Input/Output field and I want to fill it with a variable from my database.

The beginning looks like this :

```
PROGRAM  ZMCQ.

MODULE USER_COMMAND_9007 INPUT.

SELECT SINGLE FIELD1 
FROM ZTABLE_NAME INTO ??? *it doesn't work to put the field name there *
WHERE FIELD2 EQ 3.

ENDMODULE.
```

I am stuck here and I don't know how should I do that .. help please x)

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Whats the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a global variable in your Report. Than got to your to Dynpro Settings to the Tab "Elementlist" an put the variable name in line of your I/O field. 
After this you have the connection between your Dynpro-Field and a variable.